# adding items to Linked List and allocing space

Tags: c, linked-list

Here is a node for use in a linked list.

```
struct DataNode
{
    char data[3];
    struct DataNode *nextData;
};
```

and I have a function here:

```
void addDataNode(struct DataNode **DataHead, char *data)
{
    struct DataNode *temp = (struct DataNode*)(malloc(sizeof(struct DataNode)));
    struct DataNode *current = *DataHead;
    if(current == NULL){
        current = temp;
        current->nextData = NULL;
        strcpy(current->data, data);
    }else{
        while(current->nextData != NULL){
            current = current->nextData;
        }
        current->nextData = temp;
        strcpy(current->nextData->data, data);
    }
}
```

In my main, I have

```
struct DataNode *DataHead = NULL;
```

So I call the function with

```
char test[] = "Qu";
addDataNode(&DataHead, test);
```

However, outside of the function, DataHead stays NULL. Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason of the problem is that the function `addDataNode` is too complicated and as result it is difficult to see whether it sets DataHead in all its paths.:)

And indeed this was forgotten to be done in this code snippet of the function

```
if(current == NULL){
    current = temp;
    current->nextData = NULL;
    strcpy(current->data, data);
}else{
```

I suggest to rewrite the function the following way

```
void addDataNode( struct DataNode **DataHead, const char *data )
{
    struct DataNode *temp = malloc( sizeof( struct DataNode ) );

    if ( temp )
    {
        const size_t n = sizeof( temp->data );

        temo->nextData = NULL;
        strncpy( temp->data, data, n );
        temp->data[n-1] = '\0'; 

        if ( *DataHead == NULL )
        { 
            *DataHead = temp;
        }
        else
        {
            struct DataNode *current = *DataHead;

            while ( current->nextData ) current = current->nextData;

            current->nextData = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Because you don't modify `*DataHead` in your `addDataNode` function; you only read from it. You have two options: either drop the `current` variable and use `*DataHead` instead (throughout), or call `*DataHead = current` before returning.

Also, the `strcpy` is wrong. You want `strdup` instead, otherwise you into undefined memory.

Answer (score 1):

You never do anything with `DataHead` in your function, except copy what is in it into `current`, so what it *points to* (if it pointed to anything) might change, the pointer in `DataHead` itself will not.